# Dictionary get max key values else print all

Tags: c#

I've checked many solutions on different sites but couldn't find what I was looking for. I'm working on a dictionary object with different Values against Keys. The structure is as follows:

```
Key  Value
6      4
3      4
2      2
1      1
```

If they dictionary contains elements like this, the output should be 6 and 3, if Key (6) has the highest value, it should print only 6. However, if all the values are same against each key, it should print all the keys.

Trying to use the following but it only prints the highest Value.

```
var Keys_ = dicCommon.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Max(p => p.Key);
```

Any ideas

Comment: When you have text like your table use the tags `<pre> </pre>` to mark out the preformatted text so the website does not remove your linebreaks or spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Max(x=>x.Key)` use `.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Key)` and `.FirstOrDefault()` that will give you the group that has the max value. You then can itterate over the group and display whatever you need.

```
var dicCommon = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dicCommon.Add(6, 4);
dicCommon.Add(3, 4);
dicCommon.Add(2, 2);
dicCommon.Add(1, 1);

var maxGroup = dicCommon.GroupBy(x => x.Value).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
foreach (var keyValuePair in maxGroup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

[<kbd>Run Code</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mGZXk6)

Answer (score 0):

First off a query can't return one and more than one result at the same time.So you need to pick one.

In this case if you want all Keys that has the highest corresponding Value, you can sort the groups based on `Value` then just get the first group which has the highest Value:

```
var Keys_ = dicCommon.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
               .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
               .First()
               .Select(x => x.Key) 
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = String.Join(",", dicCommon
                            .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                            .First()
                            .Select(x=>x.Key));
```

Answer (score -1):

You’re almost there:

```
dicCommon.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
         .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.First().Value)
         .First().Select(pair => pair.Key).ToList()
```

`GroupBy` returns an enumerable of [`IGrouping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb344977.aspx). So sort these descending by value, then get the first, and select the key of each containing element.

---

Since this requires sorting, the runtime complexity is not linear, although we can easily do that. One way would be figuring out the maximum value first and then getting all the keys where the value is equal to that:

```
int maxValue = dicCommon.Max(x => x.Value);
List<int> maxKeys = dicCommon.Where(x => x.Value == maxValue).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think the GroupBy has deterministic ordering, you are not guaranteed that `.First()` will get the largest number.